# Got error on xcode7 for CLLocation

Tags: swift, xcode7

The error said Downcast from 'CLLocation?' only unwrap optionals; did you mean to use '!'? How Can I fix this?

```
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
   //the code below is the error i got for
    var location = locations.last as! CLLocation

    self.currentLocation = location
    var userInfo = [ LMLocationInfoKey : location]
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(LMLocationUpdateNotification as String, object:self, userInfo: userInfo)
    self.locationManager_.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: `if let lastLocation = locations.last { ...use lastLocation here  }`

Comment: `locations`it is already a `CLLocation` array, so there is no need to cast. All you need is to unwrap the first/last element

Comment: so how should code look like?